# Regex Blacklist

Tags: python

Let's say I have some code setup like this:

```
for line in open(all_data):

    line = line.strip()

    #BLACKLIST

    if not re.search(r"config/", line) and not re.search(r"html", line):

        line = re.split(r"\s+", line)
```

Where I'm excluding any line with `config/` or `html`.

If I wanted to instead make a list to feed `re.search`, how would I go about this?

For example, if I wanted to give re.search `blacklist = ['config/', 'html']`

Comment: Do you need `re`? Can't you do `not "html" in line` and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `any` function to implement this.

```
forbidden_words = [r"html", r"config/"]

for line in open(all_data):
    line = line.strip()

    #BLACKLIST
    if not any(re.search(term, line) for term in forbidden_words):
        line = re.split(r"\s+", line)
```

This is easier to see if you translate your conditional from:

```
not re.search(r"config/", line) and not re.search(r"html", line)
```

To:

```
not (re.search(r"config/", line) or re.search(r"html", line))
```

It's important to implement it this way because we know the line should be filtered out if it contains *any* forbidden word. This can take much less time to check than to ensure it doesn't contain *all* of the forbidden words.

Answer (score 0):

If it's imporant to use a single `re.search` you could use `|` operator:

```
>>> re.search(r'html|config/', r'line with config/')
<re.Match object; span=(10, 17), match='config/'>
```

For additional words you could construct the pattern using `join`:

```
words = [r'html', r'config/']
pattern = '|'.join(words)
re.search(pattern, line)
```